# The initialization, move count, and pickup command of my game aren't working correctly, what went wrong?

Tags: python, loops, infinite-loop, game-development, break

i'm making a text-based game for class, and i've run into a few snags. here's what the game is doing:

when the game initiates, it tells you where you're at, and asks where you want to go. you input that command, then it moves you to the requisite room, tells you what you see, and asks you where you want to go. if you use the pickup command to pickup the item in the room, it reiterates the room and forces you to use the pickup command again in order to collect the item. after collecting the item, it asks you where you want to go. when you input the command to go a new direction, it spins into an infinite loop that says 'you can't go that way' and won't allow you to input any further commands.

here is what i've done to try to get rid of the infinite loop, so that i could attempt to figure out the other stuff:

i've replaced my movement and direction check. i've tried introducing RETURN statements to try to end the infinite loop possibility, but it's still happening. at this point, i'm hitting my head against a wall, and i'm quite frustrated. someone please help?

```
import random
# define move_player and call
def move_player(direction):
    global player_location
    if direction in possible_moves[player_location]:
        player_location = rooms[player_location][direction]
    else:
        print("You can't go that way.")
        return
# define the collected items
def collect_item(location):
    if items.get(location):
        collected_items.append(items[location])
        print("You picked up the", items[location])
        items.pop(location)
    else:
        print("There is no item to collect.")
        return
# 'help' menu list that describes your possible actions
helpme = ('-help list- \n'
          '\nwelcome - display welcome dialogue\n'
          'commandslist - opens commands list\n'
          'quit - quits the game, you lose')
# the command list, where you have all the commands that the interact with the game itself
commandslist = ('- commands list\n'
                '\nnorth, south, east, west - directional commands for movement\n'
                'pickup - pickup the item in the room\n'
                'moves - tells you how many moves you have left\n'
                'bag - shows you what you have in your bag\n'
                'place - tells you what room you are in now\n'
                'lastplace - tells you what room you came from\n'
                'restart - restarts the game from the beginning')
# The map is 4*4, but with 2 spots removed, ' ' being no room, '.' being room
map = [[' ', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['.', '.', ' ', '.'],
       ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['.', '.', '.', '.']]
# Rooms are in order from left to right, top to bottom, with the gaps ignored.
rooms = {
    'cafeteria': {'south': 'hallway junction 1', 'east': 'lab 1'},
    'lab 1': {'south': 'observatory', 'west': 'cafeteria', 'east': 'atrium'},
    'atrium': {'south': 'You can\'t go that way.', 'west': 'You can\'t go that way.', 'east': 'lab 1'},
    'conference room': {'south': 'hallway 1', 'east': 'hallway junction 1'},
    'hallway junction 1': {'north': 'cafeteria', 'south': 'hallway 2', 'east': 'hallway junction 2', 'west': 'conference room'},
    'hallway junction 2': {'south': 'hallway 3', 'west': 'hallway junction 1'},
    'hallway 1': {'north': 'conference room', 'south': 'locker room'},
    'hallway 2': {'north': 'hallway junction 1', 'south': 'lab 2'},
    'observatory': {'north': 'lab 1', 'south': 'hallway junction 3', 'west': 'hallway 2'},
    'hallway 3': {'north': 'hallway junction 2', 'south': 'lab 3'},
    'locker room': {'north': 'hallway 1', 'east': 'lab 2'},
    'lab 2': {'north': 'hallway 2', 'west': 'locer room'},
    'hallway junction 3': {'north': 'observatory'},
    'lab 3': {'north': 'hallway 3'}
}
# Items are static in the assigned rooms
items = {
    'lab 1': 'power reduction coil',
    'lab 2': 'higgs-bosun splitter',
    'lab 3': 'quantum catalyst chip',
    'hallway junction 1': 'power reduction coil',
    'hallway junction 2': 'fluctuation meter',
    'hallway junction 3': 'tachyon attractor device',
    'conference room': 'mini nuclear bottle',
    'hallway 1': 'graviton lance',
    'hallway 2': 'airlock door hinge',
    'hallway 3': 'genetic stabilizer'
}
# Dictionary of possible moves from each room
possible_moves = {
    'cafeteria': ['south', 'east'],
    'lab 1': ['south', 'east', 'west'],
    'atrium': ['west'],
    'conference room': ['south', 'east'],
    'hallway junction 1': ['north', 'south', 'west'],
    'hallway junction 2': ['south', 'west'],
    'hallway 1': ['north', 'south'],
    'hallway 2': ['north', 'south'],
    'observatory': ['north', 'south', 'west'],
    'hallway 3': ['north', 'south'],
    'locker_room': ['north', 'east'],
    'lab 2': ['north', 'west'],
    'hallway junction 3': ['north', 'east'],
    'lab 3': ['north', 'west'],
}
# Game variables
player_location = 'observatory'
moves_remaining = 15
collected_items = []
# Game loop
while moves_remaining > 0:
# printed introduction
    print('\nYou’ve been transported to an alternate reality. The device that transported you there fell apart in\n'
      'transit, scattering on arrival. Your body is now in flux, and you must assemble the device in time and get\n'
      'to the Reality Transition Booth in the Locker Room or you will be lost as a traveler of alternate\n'
      'realities. You start in a large observatory with three doors leading out and one viewscreen for the\n'
      'telescope’s display. On this display, there’s a map that shows 14 rooms and tells you where you are.\n'
      'You know there are 10 pieces of the device that you need to find.\n'
      '\nYou need to find:\n'
      '\n- Mini Nuclear Bottle\n'
      '- Power Reduction Coil\n'
      '- Tachyon Attractor Device\n'
      '- Higgs-Bosun Splitter\n'
      '- Fluctuation Meter\n'
      '- Graviton Lance\n'
      '- Carbon Nano-tubing\n'
      '- Airlock door-hinge\n'
      '- Genetic Stabilizer\n'
      '- Quantum Catalyst Chip\n'
      '\nYour enemy is Time: you have 15 moves until you are transported to another alternate reality and are lost\n'
      'to your home to travel realities forever.\n'
      '\nYou have just been lost in place!\n')
    print("\nYou are currently in the", player_location, '\n')
    print("You have", moves_remaining, "moves left.")
# start of movement
    print("Where would you like to go? You can go:", possible_moves[player_location])
    move = input().lower()

    if move == 'quit':
        print("You lose!")
        break
    elif move == 'moves':
        print("You have", moves_remaining, "moves left.")
    elif move == 'bag':
        print("You have the following items:", collected_items)
    elif move == 'place':
        print("You are in the", player_location)
    elif move == 'lastplace':
        print("You came from the", player_location)
    elif move == 'pickup':
        collect_item(player_location)
    elif move in possible_moves[player_location]:
        last_location = player_location
        player_location = rooms[player_location][move]
        moves_remaining -= 1
        if player_location == 'You can\'t go that way.':
            print(player_location)
            player_location = last_location
    else:
        print("Invalid command.")
# Print room description
    print(rooms[player_location])
# code for getting player input and updating game state
    moves_remaining -= 1
# Check if player has reached the locker room and has collected all items
    if player_location == 'locker_room':
        if len(collected_items) == len(items):
            print("You have reached the locker room with all required items. You win!")
            break
        else:
            print("You have reached the locker room, but you don't have all the required items yet.")
    print("You have", moves_remaining, "moves remaining.")
    print("You are currently in", player_location)
    if moves_remaining == 0:
        print("You have run out of moves. Game over.")
        break
# Print collected items
    if collected_items:
        print("You have collected: ", collected_items)
    else:
        print("You haven't collected any items yet.")
# Print items in the room
    if items.get(player_location):
        print("You see: ", items[player_location])
    else:
        print("You don't see any items.")
# Prompt for next move
    direction = input("Which direction would you like to move? (north, south, east, west): ").lower()
# Check if move is valid and update player location
    if direction in possible_moves[player_location]:
        while True:
# Get the player's current location
            current_location = rooms[player_location]
# Check if the direction is valid
            if direction in current_location:
                player_location = current_location[direction]
                if player_location == 'You can\'t go that way.':
                    print(player_location)
                    continue
                else:
                    print(f'You have moved to the {player_location}.')
                    collect_item(player_location)
            else:
                print("You can't go that way.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but the piece of code
below has a high potential to run infinitely. Check the values involved, and see if rooms['You can't go that way.'][direction] equals to 'You can't go that way.'

```
while True:
        current_location = rooms[player_location]
        if direction in current_location:
            player_location = current_location[direction]
            if player_location == 'You can\'t go that way.':
                print(player_location)
                continue
```